# Cannot import Decimal module

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, decimal

I am trying to do some simple decimal math to practice with the Tkinter GUI, but for some reason I cannot import Decimal:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 139, in <module>
    import math as _math
  File "math.py", line 3, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
ImportError: cannot import name Decimal
```

I am using Python 2.7.11
This is making me feel pretty stupid since it seems like a simple thing to do. Is Decimal not supported or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: i'll recommend a re-install of python, because this is a local issue

Comment: Could inspect the decimal module and see what names are available `import decimal; dir(decimal)`

Comment: You should consider [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668125/4575793) to troubleshoot problems like this.

Answer (score 4):

You called a file `math.py`, meaning it overrides the built-in `math` module and breaks everything that uses that module. Pick a different name, and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue of Python 3+ not being able to import `Decimal`.
Even some external libraries, like `pygal`, would not install because the system could not access `Decimal` and `decimal` library.

I found accidentally in another site that "there maybe another `decimal.py` file in your system, shadowing on the decimal library".

I checked and found out that I had named a test file (while I was learning Python) as `decimal.py` and after I renamed this to `decimaltest.py` everything is working perfect.

Check if you have done the same or you have any similar wrongly named file in your system.

Comment: Hint for the next answer: you should include a reference to the page you're quoting.