# Updating DateTimeField in Django

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I have a DateTimeField() in my models.py. What I am trying to do is to update it, along with some other values in the model.

Everything else updates fine apart from my DateTimeField(). the error i get says that `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'`

anyone see where I am going wrong with m update?

```
sModel.objects.all().update(sPasses=pass_number_for_graph, sFails=fail_number_for_graph, sNds=p_number_for_graph, sTimestamp=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639415/attributeerror-module-datetime-has-no-attribute-now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import _datetime as instead of datetime

```
import _datetime
```